# Android - touch listener with finger

Tags: android, touch, listener

I have only this code, but this is not good idea.

How can make left click listener with finger, in Android ?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onTouchEvent(event);

    int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    float x1 = 0, x2 = 0;

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
              x1 = event.getX();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
              x2 = event.getX();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is wrong with your code?

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to identify a click with th left hand/finger?

If correct then there is no way to do this that I am aware of...